# Can I make ungetc unblock a blocking fgetc call?

Tags: c, stdin, blocking

I would like to stuff an 'A' character back into stdin using ungetc on receipt of SIGUSR1.  Imagine that I have a good reason for doing this.

When calling foo(), the blocking read in stdin is not interrupted by the ungetc call on receipt of the signal.  While I didn't expect this to work as is, I wonder if there is a way to achieve this - does anyone have suggestions?

```
void handler (int sig)
{
  ungetc ('A', stdin);
}

void foo ()
{
  signal (SIGUSR1, handler);

  while ((key = fgetc (stdin)) != EOF)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than try to get `ungetc()` to unblock a blocking `fgetc()` call via a signal, perhaps you could try not having `fgetc()` block to begin with and wait for activity on stdin using `select()`.

---

By default, the line discipline for a terminal device may work in canonical mode. In this mode, the terminal driver doesn't present the buffer to userspace until the newline is seen (<kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed).

To accomplish what you want, you can set the terminal into raw (non-canonical) mode by using `tcsetattr()` to manipulate the `termios` structure.  This should case the blocking call to `fgetc()` to immediately return the character inserted with `ungetc()`.

```
void handler(int sig) {
   /* I know I shouldn't do this in a signal handler,
    * but this is modeled after the OP's code.
    */
   ungetc('A', stdin);
}

void wait_for_stdin() {
   fd_set fdset;
   FD_ZERO(&fdset);
   FD_SET(fileno(stdin),&fdset);
   select(1, &fdset, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}

void foo () {
   int key;
   struct termios terminal_settings;

   signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

   /* set the terminal to raw mode */
   tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &terminal_settings);
   terminal_settings.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO|ICANON);
   terminal_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
   terminal_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
   tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &terminal_settings);

   for (;;) {
      wait_for_stdin();
      key = fgetc(stdin);
      /* terminate loop on Ctrl-D */
      if (key == 0x04) {
         break;
      }      
      if (key != EOF) {
         printf("%c\n", key);
      }
   }
}
```

**NOTE: This code omits error checking for simplicity.**


Clearing the `ECHO` and `ICANON` flags respectively disables echoing of characters as they are typed and causes read requests to be satisfied directly from the input queue.  Setting the values of `VTIME` and `VMIN` to zero in the `c_cc` array causes the read request (`fgetc()`) to return immediately rather than block; effectively polling stdin.  This causes `key` to get set to `EOF` so another method for terminating the loop is necessary.  Unnecessary polling of stdin is reduced by waiting for activity on stdin using `select()`.


Executing the program, sending a `SIGUSR1` signal, and typing
<kbd>t</kbd> <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> results in the following output<sup>1</sup>:

```
A
t
e
s
t
```

<sup>1) tested on Linux</sup>

Comment: Shouldn't that be `terminal_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;`? to return when at least 1 character is available?

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what your goal is, but is this what you are looking for?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int handle = 0;

void handler (int sig) {
  handle = 1;
}

void foo () {
  int key;

  signal (SIGUSR1, handler);

  while ((key = fgetc (stdin)) != EOF) {
    printf("%c\n",key);
    if (handle) {
      handle = 0;
      ungetc('A',stdin);
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  printf("PID: %d\n",getpid());
  foo();
}
```

It produces this output:

```
PID: 8902
test (typed on stdin)
t
A
e
s
t
```

Comment: Not quite - I'm looking for a way to get that 'A' ahead of the 't'.

Answer (score 1):

FILE*s are not async safe.

You cannot operate on a FILE* in a signal handler while someone else also uses that same FILE*. functions you can all in a signal handler is stated here:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html . (It might be 
different on a windows machine, but still any FILE* are not safe there either.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as @Jamie's answer, slightly changed to support your desire to process the `A` before the `t`, but it's too hard to type code into a comment box, so I've posted this answer separately.

```
int insert_an_A = 0;
void handler(int sig) { insert_an_A = 1; }

void process_char(char c) { ... }

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    /* skip signal setup */
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        if (insert_an_A) {
            process_char('A');
            insert_an_A = 0;
        }
        process_char(c);
    }
}
```

If you want to process an handler received during the call to `fgetc` that returns `EOF`, you should also check `insert_an_A` after exiting the while loop.

Note also that in general the best practice for signal handlers is to set a global variable and return from the handler.  Elsewhere in your program, look for that variable changing and react appropriately.