# Program won't end after catching SIGINT before pressing ENTER?

Tags: c, volatile, sigint, signal-handling

Why does my program not end until I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in terminal after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>?

Here is my code:

```
static volatile sig_atomic_t keepRunning = 1;

void intHandler(int sig) 
{
    keepRunning = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    signal(SIGINT, intHandler);

    int ch; 
    while((ch = fgetc(stdin)) && keepRunning)
    {
      ...
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have setup my while loop to read chars from stdin and to run until the `SIGINT` is caught. After that the `keepRunning` will be set to `0` and loop should end and terminate the program. However when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> my program doesn't accept any input anymore but it doesn't let me type any command in terminal until I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key. Why is that?

Comment: @twodayslate it is still the same after that

Comment: What is in the `while` loop? Is it a `pause` or [`sigsuspend`](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Sigsuspend.html)?

Comment: @jww I am just parsing the string that I enter and then printing it

Comment: The problem here is the use of `signal`. You should always use `sigaction`

Comment: On my computer the `signal` will set a handler that will automatically restart the system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `fgetc()` is blocking the execution, and the way you chose to handle SIGINT - `fgetc()` will NOT be interrupted with EINTR (see @AnttiHaapala's answer for further explanation). So only after you press enter, which releases `fgetc()`, keepRunning is being evaluated.

The terminal is also buffered, so only when you press enter it will send the chars to the `FILE *` buffer and will read by `fgetc()` one by one. This is why it exists only after pressing enter, and not other keys.

One of several options to "solve" it is to use nonblocking stdin, signalfd and epoll (if you use linux):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <sys/signalfd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <error.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sigset_t mask;
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGINT);

    /* Block signals so that they aren't handled
       according to their default dispositions */
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL); // need check

    // let's treat signal as fd, so we could add to epoll
    int sfd = signalfd(-1, &mask, 0); // need check

    int epfd = epoll_create(1); // need check

    // add signal to epoll
    struct epoll_event ev = { .events = EPOLLIN, .data.fd = sfd };
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sfd, &ev); // need check

    // Make STDIN non-blocking 
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    // add STDIN to epoll
    ev.data.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, STDIN_FILENO, &ev); // need check

    char ch;
    int keepRunning = 1; // no need to synchronize anymore
    while(keepRunning) {
        epoll_wait(epfd, &ev, 1, -1); // need check, must be always 1
        if (ev.data.fd == sfd) {
            printf("signal caught\n");
            keepRunning = 0;
        } else {
            ssize_t r;
            while(r = read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1) > 0) {
                printf("%c", ch);
            }
            if (r == 0 && errno == 0) { 
                /* non-blocking non-eof will return 0 AND EAGAIN errno */
                printf("EOF reached\n");
                keepRunning = 0;
            } else if (errno != EAGAIN) {
                perror("read");
                keepRunning = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETFL) & ~O_NONBLOCK);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Also note that I'm not using `fgetc()`. Because of buffering nature of `FILE *`, it will not work well with nonblocking IO.

The program above is intended for education purposes only and not for "production" use. There are several issue that need attention, for example:

- All the libc / system calls need to tested for errors.
- If output is slower than input (`printf()` may easily be slower), it may cause starvation and the signal will not get caught (the inner loop will exit only after input is over/slower).
- Performance / reduction of system calls:

  - `read()` can fill much larger buffer.
  - `epoll_wait` can return multiple events instead of 1.

Comment: is there a way to solve with keeping `fgetc()`? Or is it totally fine to be like this?

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620010/can-i-make-ungetc-unblock-a-blocking-fgetc-call

Comment: It is not actually true.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what is not true? that `fgetc()` is blocking? it is. There are other ways to unblock, but that is not the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Usually system calls return with `errno == EINTR` if a signal was delivered when they're blocking, which would cause `fgetc` to return early with an error condition as soon as Control-C was hit. The problem is that the signal set by `signal` will be set to auto restarting mode, i.e. the underlying `read` system call would be restarted as soon as the signal handler completed.

The correct fix would be to remove the automatic restart but it does make it slightly trickier to use correctly. Here we see if the return value is `EOF` from `fgetc` and then if it is caused by `EINTR` and restart the loop if the boolean was not true.

```
struct sigaction action = {
    .sa_flags = 0,
    .sa_handler = intHandler
};
sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);

int ch;
while (1) {
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
    if (ch == EOF) {
        if (errno == EINTR) {
            if (keepRunning) {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: not explaining the behavior of the original problem therefore not really answering the question. Your suggestion is to stop blocking calls which defeats the purpose of handling the signal in the manner the question suggest - finish processing the loop and only then exit.

Comment: If the loop has any other blocking calls it will get cancelled too.

Comment: @niry and your approach does not explain how to stop `fgetc`, it explains how to replace it.

Comment: true. the question is why it is happening (not how to stop `fgetc()`, which you are  answering) I'm suggesting completely different approach to achieve what would be presumed a desired behavior.

Comment: @niry and I did  answer *why* it is happening: because the `signal` function sets a handler that is *auto-restarting*. It does not have anything to do with `fgetc` being blocking.

Comment: as I said the first comment, your suggestion with interrupting calls will defeat the purpose of handling interrupts in that manner... the whole idea on handling interrupt and setting a variable somewhere is to *control* when to leave the program, not to interrupt calls.

Comment: @niry incorrect. The purpose of `EINTR` is to interrupt blocking calls, for this very reason. It does not defeat the purpose, it is exactly why `EINTR` exists.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202486/discussion-between-niry-and-antti-haapala).